# How to compare different facial images on Matlab without using data set?

Tags: matlab, face-recognition

I am working on a Matlab facial recognition project.

What I have to do is to read two different images of same person side by side and extract their local features (like eyes, nose and mouth).

My code reads images and detects features, I need a function for comparing any two face images and tell if they're of the same person or not?

The code is given below.

```
clear all;
clc

% Read the input image
I = imread('12.jpg');
I2 = imread('1.jpg');
I=rgb2gray(I);
I2=rgb2gray(I2);


%Detect objects using Viola-Jones Algorithm

%To detect Face
FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
BB=step(FaceDetect,I);
BB1 = insertObjectAnnotation(I,'rectangle',BB,'Face');
hn1 = imhist(BB)./numel(BB);

h1=subplot(1,2,1);

imshow(I);imshow(BB1); hold on




title('Facial Feature Detection');
%To detect Mouth
MouthDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Mouth','MergeThreshold',180);
BB=step(MouthDetect,I);
 hold on
for i = 1:size(BB,1)
 rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','r');
end
%To detect Nose
NoseDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose','MergeThreshold',12);
BB=step(NoseDetect,I);

 hold on
for i = 1:size(BB,1)
    rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','b');
end

%To detect Eyes
EyeDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('EyePairBig');
BB=step(EyeDetect,I);
hold on
rectangle('Position',BB,'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','g');
%imshow(BB1);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%---FACIAL FEATURES OF 2ND IMAGE----%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%To detect Face
FaceDetect2 = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
BB2=step(FaceDetect2,I2);
B = insertObjectAnnotation(I2,'rectangle',BB2,'Face');
hn2 = imhist(BB2)./numel(BB2);

h2=subplot(1,2,2);

imshow(I2);imshow(B); hold on


title('Facial Feature Detection');
%To detect Mouth
MouthDetect2 = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Mouth','MergeThreshold',160);
BB2=step(MouthDetect2,I2);
 hold on
for i = 1:size(BB2,1)
 rectangle('Position',BB2(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','r');
end
%To detect Nose
NoseDetect2 = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose','MergeThreshold',12);
BB2=step(NoseDetect2,I2);

 hold on
for i = 1:size(BB2,1)
    rectangle('Position',BB2(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','b');
end

%To detect Eyes
EyeDetect2 = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('EyePairBig');
BB2=step(EyeDetect2,I2);
hold on
rectangle('Position',BB2,'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','g');
linkaxes([h2,h1])

score_euclidean = norm(hn1-hn2);
 %score_euclidean = pdist2(feature1, feature2);

%Set a threshold for euclidean similarity where smaller is more similar
euclidean_threshold = 0.1;
disp('Euclidean Compare')
disp(score_euclidean)
if score_euclidean < euclidean_threshold 
    disp('similar images');
else
    disp('dissimilar images');
end
```

Comment: This is a pretty hard problem to solve with CascadeObjectDetector: it will only return bounding boxes for features that you request for. It only does detection, but not recognition. Have you looked at https://www.mathworks.com/videos/face-recognition-with-matlab-100902.html ? Using the features that are used to recognize faces, you could potentially build a classifier.

Comment: I need a function to compare two faces without using database!

Comment: This is a very difficult problem without a database.  It's relatively straight forward to perform a face detection, but to detect whether two faces are the same without a database of images is near impossible.  Feature-based methods are designed to be robust amidst rotation, translation, perspective and other variations.  Without a database, all you can rely on is whether you're seeing a face.

Comment: Checkout FaceNet, which when pretrained, maps faces to euclidean-space. There you can do the usual stuff as nearest-neighbor searches or distance-computations. There are some very popular implementations (e.g. [openface](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface)) although these are mostly python/lua-torch. You need to check if there is a matlab-alternative.

Comment: According to me the euclidean distance should have done the trick. I wonder what is stopping it from that. Can you may be upload some images of your results?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe give the right answer:
You can measure the distance between the eyes or the length of the lips, etc. for each photo and compare them...